# How can i gain focus again on the textbox without an exception for my following code?

Tags: c#

I have a form, and i performed validations on my textboxes as specified below..For the below code, when i press the 'clear' button, the textboxes get emptied, and then, When i am trying to focus on any textbox( i.e, i am trying to click on any textbox ) to enter some new text, then an InvalidCastException occurs.. why so ???

```
namespace ex_validation
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                txtuserid.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
                txtpassword.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
                txtage.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
                btnnextform.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
                btnclear.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
            }
            public void Dovalidation(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;// " EXCEPTION OCCURS AT THIS LINE "
                if (t.Text=="")
                {
                    t.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;// sets the backcolor of the textbox if found empty
                    e.Cancel = true;// cancel all other events unless user enters something in that relevant textbox
                }
                else
                    t.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }

            private void txtage_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }

            private void txtage_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtage.Text == "")
                    MessageBox.Show("Age field cannot be left blank");
                else
                {
                    int x = System.Convert.ToInt16(txtage.Text);
                    if (x < 1 || x > 100)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Age cannot be above 100 OR below 1", "Prompt Box", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        txtage.Clear();
                        txtage.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void btnnextform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 f = new Form2();
                f.Show();
            }

            private void btnclear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                txtuserid.Text = (string)"";
                txtpassword.Text = (string)"";
                txtage.Text = (string)"";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: btnnextform and btnclear are not a Textbox-es I guess and still you try to validate as if it is. That is the root cause...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You register `Dovalidation` to events on controls *other* than `TextBox` so the cast fails, namely `btnnextform` and `btnclear`.

Don't explicitly cast in instances where the cast will fail (or do so and handle the possible exception). There are two easy ways to guard against invalid casts upfront:

1) Use `as` with a null check:

```
TextBox t = sender as TextBox;

if (t != null)
{
    // We have a textbox.
}

Button b = sender as Button; // etc
```

2) Test the type with `is` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
if (sender is TextBox)
{
    TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
}
```

But you will then need to cast as normal, so I tend to stick with `as` in this situation.

The `as` [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is similar to explicit casting, but if a cast isn't possible it instead returns `null` instead of throwing the exception.

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions,
>   nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't
>   perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which
>   should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

---

**Alternatively:**

However, that said, if you need to do different validation against the buttons as against the text boxes, you might just want to have another separate validation method - this will produce a simpler and smaller set of methods, as opposed to one method trying to do everything.

Comment: You've answered 20 secs before me:)

Comment: Oh yeah !! i am not supposed to assign an EventHandler to  buttons.. (btnclear & btnnextform are buttons).. now its working finely.. thnks fr d help..

Answer (score 1):

Because your validation handler expects sender to be a text box only, but you attach it to button too

Comment: yeah right !! i just removed these 2 lines-
btnnextform.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
btnclear.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(Dovalidation);
And now its wrking properly..